# game collision - if something is true

Tags: swift, game-physics, collision

I made a game. Like the color switch game! I have:
I have more than one swift file to do actions.

```
Player-->where I made the player
Block -->same with the blocks ("enemies"
Blockgenerator-->actually made the blocks
GameScene---> touch begins...
```

So the main thing is that there's a player and then blocks come in 4 colors. Red green blue black. If i touch the screen the player change it's color (red green blue black..,same as blocks)

But the player collide with every block. I want the player to collide if the player and block color aren't the same. A blue player should walk through a block like a ghost. How can i do that?
Xcode,swift. Used physic categories.

Comment: Have you already tried to come up with an implementation for this "only detect collision if blocks aren't same colour as player" system?  If so, what have you tried, how did it fail, and how close did it come to satisfactory behaviour?

Comment: If you haven't tried anything yet, one thing I would suggest trying is using flags to indicate the player's, and each blocks', colour.  This way, you can short-circuit the collision detection, so that it skips detection if the player and the block have the same colour flag.  Not sure how to implement that in Swift, but it might be possible.

Comment: If I send you the code can you look into and see how I made it and maybe you can tell how to solve the problem

Comment: I'm not familiar with Swift, unfortunately.  Sorry.